# How to mock Java.net.URL class using EasyMock

Tags: java, groovy

As we know URL is a final class so can any one  tell me how I can mock that class while writing the test cases using EasyMock.

I am writing the test case for one method which is using URL looking like this.

```
public String call() {
    //some logics
    URL url=new URL("url name")
}
```

So how I can mock URL while writing the test case for call method

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use pure `EasyMock` to mock final classes/methods.  However, it can be done with `PowerMock` extension as [explained here](https://www.journaldev.com/22338/easymock-final-method-powermock-junit-testng).

Or you may wrap the URL into some non-final class which can be mocked:

```
class MyURL {
    private URL url;
    public MyURL(URL url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public URLConnection openConnection() throws IOException {
        return url.openConnection();
    }
// ... etc.
}
```